# MS SQL copy data from another table by rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I have following 2 tables:

[image]

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (
    [NO] int,
    A1 float, 
    A2 float, 
    A3 float, 
    A4 float, 
    A5 float,
    A6 float
)

DECLARE @table2 TABLE (
    KOD nvarchar(100), 
    ID_QUANTITY int
)

INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES
(1, 4.1, 3, 3.5, 23.5, 12.2, 2.4),
(2, 4.2, 0, 1.9, 34.5, 31.2, 34.2),
(3, 1.5, 0, 2.3, 12.3, 12.3, 1.2),
(4, 3.7, 2.1, 5.9, 4.8, 10.2, 21.2),
(5, 3.9, 2.6, 1.9, 12.3, 2.4, 10.2)

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES
('A1', 500),
('A2', 600),
('A3', 700),
('A4', 800),
('A5', 900),
('A6', 1000)
```

And I need create script in sql for transform value in first table to appearance as below

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: Provide DDL and insert script with sample data instead of pictures.

Comment: Beside the fact, that your pictures would force any one helping you to type in your data (please provide copy'n'paste DDL and sample data), there's some more question: Is "A6" the highest ever? Or there be A7, A8 too. Is it possible that values are missing? Might a whole column be missing (A1,A3, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

[UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) then JOIN, use ROW_NUMBER() for `ID` column:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as ID,
        ID_QUANTITY,
        [VALUES]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    ) p
UNPIVOT (
    [VALUES] FOR [COL] IN (A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6)
) as unpvt
LEFT JOIN table2 t 
    ON t.KOD = unpvt.[COL]
ORDER BY ID_QUANTITY, [NO]
```

Output:

```
ID  ID_QUANTITY VALUES
1   500         4,1
2   500         4,2
3   500         1,5
4   500         3,7
5   500         3,9
6   600         3
7   600         0
8   600         0
9   600         2,1
10  600         2,6
...
25  900         2,4
26  1000        2,4
27  1000        34,2
28  1000        1,2
29  1000        21,2
30  1000        10,2
```

Comment: Dam you beat me too it.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNPIVOT

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
    t2.ID_Quantity,
    t1.Value 
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN 
(
            SELECT * 
            FROM Table1
            UNPIVOT 
            (
                [Values] FOR [Columns] IN ([A1], [A2],[A3], [A4], [A5],[A6])
            ) as pvt
) t1
ON t1.Columns = t2.KOD
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

create `table3`(`ID_QUANTITY` int(11),`VALUE` int(11));

`for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){
$insert=mysql_query("insert into table3 select a.ID_QUANTITY,b.A$i from table2 a,table1 b where a.KOD='A$i');
}`